# for-loop with key-value pair, the key is sort order is not maintained

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have below script, i noticed that the for-loop in this case is executing in order other than i specified ie. expected 2018,2019,2020 but comes out as 2019,2018,2020.

Is there a specific reason for that in shell scripting, is there any way to preserve the order.

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -A arr
arr=( ["2018"]=5%12 ["2019"]=1%12 ["2020"]=1%2 )
INPUT_MONTH=$2
INPUT_YEAR=$1

#For loop to iterate the year(key) value of array
for year in ${!arr[@]}; do
  echo  ${year} ${arr[${year}]}
  MONTH_RANGE=${arr[${year}]}
  if [ ${year} -ge ${INPUT_YEAR} ]; then
    START_MONTH=$(echo "${MONTH_RANGE}" | cut -d'%' -f 1)
    END_MONTH=$(echo "${MONTH_RANGE}" | cut -d'%' -f 2)
    # input year is equal and input month is different from default start one.
    if [ "${year}" == "${INPUT_YEAR}" ]; then
      START_MONTH=$INPUT_MONTH
    fi
    for mon in $(seq $START_MONTH $END_MONTH); do
      echo "Process year:month <=> ${year}:${mon}"
    done;
  else
    continue;
  fi
done;
```

output:

```
2019 1%12
Process year:month <=> 2019:1
Process year:month <=> 2019:2
Process year:month <=> 2019:3
Process year:month <=> 2019:4
Process year:month <=> 2019:5
Process year:month <=> 2019:6
Process year:month <=> 2019:7
Process year:month <=> 2019:8
Process year:month <=> 2019:9
Process year:month <=> 2019:10
Process year:month <=> 2019:11
Process year:month <=> 2019:12
2018 5%12
Process year:month <=> 2018:4
Process year:month <=> 2018:5
Process year:month <=> 2018:6
Process year:month <=> 2018:7
Process year:month <=> 2018:8
Process year:month <=> 2018:9
Process year:month <=> 2018:10
Process year:month <=> 2018:11
Process year:month <=> 2018:12
2020 1%2
Process year:month <=> 2020:1
Process year:month <=> 2020:2
```

Comment: Is your `/bin/sh` bash? if so, I think that's expected since you are using an **associative** array (see for example [How to keep associative array order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29161460) ). Since your keys (years) appear to be numeric, have you considered using an indexed array instead?

Comment: yes it is. Ok now i understand that associative arrays doesn't preserve orders. Nope i didn't use indexes. but i have seen reference of it. For my requirement the order doesn't matter by i was queries to know abt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, `declare -A arr` declares an *associative* array. The keys in an associative array are hashed and the traversal order of `${!arr[@]}` is not guaranteed<sup>1</sup>.

```
$ declare -A arr
$ arr=( ["2018"]=5%12 ["2019"]=1%12 ["2020"]=1%2 )
$ for year in "${!arr[@]}"; do printf '%s: %s\n' "${year}" "${arr[${year}]}"; done
2019: 1%12
2018: 5%12
2020: 1%2
```

In contrast, `declare -a arr` declares an *indexed* array, which should sort as you expect:

```
$ declare -a arr
$ arr=( [2018]=5%12 [2019]=1%12 [2020]=1%2 )
$ for year in "${!arr[@]}"; do printf '%s: %s\n' "${year}" "${arr[${year}]}"; done
2018: 5%12
2019: 1%12
2020: 1%2
```

Since your keys (years) are numeric, there seems to be no reason not to use an indexed array in this context.

---

*References:*

1. [How to keep associative array order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29161460)

Answer (score 1):

In this case the keys happen to be numbers so you can use steeldriver's solution.

The general approach would be to have an additional array for the key order:

```
declare -a ordered_keys
ordered_keys=(2018 2019 2020)
# or dynamically
ordered_keys=($(for key in "${!arr[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "$key"; done | sort))
```

And then instead of

```
for year in ${!arr[@]}; do
```

you do

```
for key in "${ordered_keys[@]}"; do
```